# NHibernate 3 QueryOver one to many

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have this nhibernate query

```
        var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

        var users = session.QueryOver<User>()
            .Where(u => u.Enabled)
            .WhereRestrictionOn(u=>u.Orders).IsNull
            .Inner.JoinQueryOver<Foo>(a => a.Foos).Where(c => c.Enabled)
            .Inner.JoinQueryOver<Bar>(m => m.Bars).Where(m => m.Enabled)
            .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
            .List();
```

WhereRestrictionOn Orders doesn't work

but I am trying to ensure these users have zero orders but have Foos and Bars

Can anyone help with a way to do it in NHibernate?

Update:

Here is how I changed this so far - seems to work

```
        var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        User rawUser = null;

        var existing = QueryOver.Of<Order>().Where(x => x.UserID == rawUser.UserID).Select(x=>x.User);

        var users = session.QueryOver<User>(() => rawUser)
            .Where(u => u.Enabled)
            .WithSubquery.WhereNotExists(existing)
            .Inner.JoinQueryOver<Foo>(a => a.Foos).Where(c => c.Enabled)
            .Inner.JoinQueryOver<Bar>(m => m.Bars).Where(m => m.Enabled)
            .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
            .List();
```

Comment: Do you know what the generated SQL looks like ? (NHProf is a good tool for that)

Comment: looked at NHProf and in the where statement its adding where userid is null

Comment: @chrisg, Could you please add the sql query that you are trying to write in queryover??